# CPU Spiking But Top 10 Queries Are Not Resource Intensive

Tags: sql-server

This is a strange issue that I have been trying to trouble shoot.  For the past few months our production CPU will just spike despite the load that I am running on it.  Specifically, the spiking is usually occurring at night (8:00 PM) when there are not a lot of users in the system.  I am using Red Gate Monitor and Red Gate reports that the instance CPU is only around 33% and the host CPU is at 100%.  Thus, I am not sure if this is a SQL Server issue or a VM issue.  I looked at the top 10 queries at this time and each are running under a second.  Should I be looking at waits too?  We are using SQL 2012 on a virtual machine (VMWare).

Comment: Look for other processes running on your server, could be a various amount of things. What backup solution do you use?

Comment: How much RAM does the server have? And what is max mem set to? Are there any scheduled tasks at that time? Server backup? Antivirus?

Comment: Our production server has 160 Gigs of RAM. We are allocating 136 gugs SQL Server.  The top ten processes for CPU as reported by Red Gate Monitor during the crash only amount to 16% of CPU. SQL Server is the top process at 12.29%.  Thus, not too much else going on.  Our backups happen at 11:00 PM which is 2.5 hours before this CPU spike. It is the host CPU that is spiking well beyond the SQL instance CPU.  Specifically, at 9:00 PM I see 94% CPU for Host and only 33% at the instance.

Comment: We thought it was additional processes like Agent Jobs, etc, but I turned all of those off one weekend and the server still crashed b/c of CPU spiking.  Hard to troubleshoot if it might be a non SQL Server related issue.